# Unexpected behaviour with getBean(String beanName, Object args)

Tags: spring

I am using `getBean(beanName,new Object{"anupama"})` to override the constructor value static factory method used in my spring bean . But it still picking the default value mentioned in `spring-application.xml` and not picking it up from `getBean()` .

Code:

```
<beans
      xmlns="springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="springframework.org/schema/beans springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd"
      default-lazy-init="false">
   <bean id="oneServiceImplementation"
         class="sample.oneServiceImplementation"
         factory-method="getInstance"
         scope="prototype">
      <constructor-arg value="anu"/>
   </bean>
</beans>
```

In my class:

```
Object returnObj = reference.getFactory().getBean("oneServiceImplementation",
                   new Object{"anupama"} );
```

Above call should pass parameter anupama to getInstance(String) method but I get the default "anu" in getInstance(String) method.

Comment: Show us the bean definition, otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd" default-lazy-init="false">

Comment: <bean id="oneServiceImplementation" class="sample.oneServiceImplementation" factory-method="getInstance" scope="prototype">
                <constructor-arg value="anu"/>
  </bean>
</beans>

Comment: Object returnObj = reference.getFactory().getBean("oneServiceImplementation",new Object{"anupama"} );

Comment: Above call should pass parameter anupama to getInstance(String) method but I get the default "anu" in getInstance(String) method.

Comment: @skaffman I've edited the comments of anupama into the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does not even compile :

```
new Object{"anupama"}
```

If oneServiceImplementation.getInstance expects a String, than you should provide one :

```
Object returnObj = reference.getFactory().getBean("oneServiceImplementation","anupama" );
```